# main() and Closure Compiler

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

I have some javascript that runs fine after being compiled through Closure with `SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS`. But I would like to perform `ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS` which performs dead code removal.

After reading some relevant documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/api-tutorial3#removal), I believe my `main()` function, which I call through `<body onload="main()">` is being eliminated by my compiler. To confirm this, I put a `console.log('hello');` line of code in my `main()` function. When opening up the results of Closure compilation with simple and advanced optimizations in a text editor, I can find that `console.log('hello');` in the simple version, but it is not present in the advanced version.

So my question is, is there an elegant way to tell the compiler that `main()` is not unreachable? (Or perhaps am I doing something else wrong..)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bind it with an event listener instead of inlining it in your html. For example instead of:

**HTML**

```
<body onload="main()">Test</body>
```

**JS**

```
var main = function() { /* Do something */ }
```

Use

**New JS**

```
var main = function() {
    console.log("Here!");
}
window.addEventListener("load", main);
```

Then you can remove `onload="main()"` from your HTML. This is also considered good practice in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `--closure_entry_point` flag. Whatever file has `main` in it, put something like `goog.provide('myapp.entrypoint')` in that file, and then pass `--closure_entry_point=myapp.entrypoint` to the compiler.